# python pandas shift next rows for values

Tags: python, pandas, shift

I use pandas:
input:

```
import pandas as pd
a=pd.Series([0,0,1,0,0,0,0])
```

output:

```
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    0
4    0
5    0
6    0
```

I want to get data for next rows in same values:

output:

```
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    1
6    0
```

use

```
a+a.shift(1)+a.shift(2)+a.shift(3)
```

I think this is not a smart solution
who have a smart solution for this

Answer (score 0):

You can try this assuming index 6 should be value `1` too,

```
a=pd.Series([0,0,1,0,0,0,0])
a.eq(1).cumsum()

Out[19]: 
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    1
6    1
dtype: int32
```

Updated : More than one value not equal to 0.

```
a=pd.Series([0,0,1,0,1,3,0])
a.ne(0).cumsum()
A=pd.DataFrame({'a':a,'Id':a.ne(0).cumsum()})
A.groupby('Id').a.cumsum()


Out[58]: 
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    3
6    3
```

Or you can use `ffill`

```
a[a.eq(0)]=np.nan
a.ffill().fillna(0)

Out[64]: 
0    0.0
1    0.0
2    1.0
3    1.0
4    1.0
5    3.0
6    3.0
```

Comment: can just do `cumsum` any reason for the `eq(1)` bitwise comparison?

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane updated . but you are right , previous approach do not need `eq`

Answer (score 0):

1 You could filter the series for "your" value (SearchValue).

2 Re-index the dataseries to a to-be-stated length (LengthOfIndex) and forward fill the "your" a given number of times (LengthOfFillRange)

3 Fill it with zeros again.

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 a=pd.Series([0,0,1,0,0,0,0])
 SearchValue       = 1
 LengthOfIndex     = 7
 LengthOfFillRange = 4
 a=a[a==SearchValue]\
     .reindex(np.linspace(1,LengthOfIndex,LengthOfIndex, dtype='int32'),
              method='ffill',
              limit=LengthOfFillRange)\
     .fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need repeat only 2 values Series by some limit use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) for `NaN`s, then `ffill` ([`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with method `ffill`) and last `fillna` for convert `NaN`s to original values (and if necessary convert to int):

```
a=pd.Series([0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,])
print (a)
0     0
1     0
2     1
3     0
4     0
5     0
6     0
7     1
8     0
9     0
10    0
dtype: int64

b= a.replace(0,np.nan).ffill(limit=2).fillna(0).astype(a.dtype)
print (b)
0     0
1     0
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     0
6     0
7     1
8     1
9     1
10    0
dtype: int64
```